# in asp.net how can I dynamically hide one field based off anothers value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 4 asp:Textbox fields on a form.  IDs being A1, A2 and B1, B2 for simplicity.
If any one of the As or Bs is populated, I need to hide the other one.  So I enter something in A1, hide A2, enter something in B2, hide B1.

I thought I could use a javascript OnBlur event to do this but it doesn't do anything unfortunately.  I'm trying to get the fields to appear/disappear without having to do a postback.

Any suggestions or examples would be great.

thanks,
Q

Comment: Any code samples demonstrating the problem would be great.

Comment: yeah, sorry, not at work today so I don't have access to my coding... probably should of wrote this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

piece of cake, and without jQuery :P

```
<script>
    function txtChange(x1, x2){
        x1=document.getElementById(x1);
        x2=document.getElementById(x2);
        x2.style['display'] = (x1.value.length>0) ? 'none' : '';
    }
</script>
```

and

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a1.Attributes["onchange"] = string.Format("txtChange('{0}','{1}')", a1.ClientID, a2.ClientID);
    a2.Attributes["onchange"] = string.Format("txtChange('{0}','{1}')", a2.ClientID, a1.ClientID);
    b1.Attributes["onchange"] = string.Format("txtChange('{0}','{1}')", b1.ClientID, b2.ClientID);
    b2.Attributes["onchange"] = string.Format("txtChange('{0}','{1}')", b2.ClientID, b1.ClientID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the event trigger `onKeyDown` to your four text boxes (You can read about key press event handlers here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljlkwans.php) and use the handler to hide the unwanted text box.  Or if you just want to disable and not hide it this will work for you:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="A1" onKeyDown="disableText('A2')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then for the javascript:

```
function disableText(textbox)
{
    document.getElementById(textbox).disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: Why does he need AJAX? All he's trying to do is on client side. That's pure javascript.

Comment: Looking at that code and logically thinking about it, that will disable it but lets say they want to delete all of the text and then use A2 instead of A1, you would need to add a check to the function that sees if the text box is empty, then unhide all "A" text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('#A1').blur(function(){
    if ($('#A1').value() == "")
    {
        $('#A2').fadeIn();
    }
    else
    { 
        $('#A2').fadeOut();
    }
    });
});
```

Though if you're using a master page id's will be different!

Comment: lol @ jQuery, it seems noone wants to write vanilla JS anymore :)

Comment: Nobody who has used jquery or a similar framework would want to use vanilla js, it sucks in comparison.